# Find the fourth roots of the following binomial surd: $14+8\sqrt{3}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Find the fourth roots of the following binomial surd: $X=14+8\sqrt{3}$

I attempt to find the square root first: $\sqrt{X}=\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}}$

$\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{y_1}$

$(\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}})^2=(\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{y_1})^2$

$14+8\sqrt{3}=x_1+y_1+2\sqrt{x_1y_1}$

$x_1+y_1=14$; $2\sqrt{x_1y_1}=8\sqrt{3} \Rightarrow x_1y_1=48$

$(x_1-y_1)^2=(x_1+y_1)^2-4x_1y_1 \Rightarrow (x_1-y_1)^2=(14)^2-4(48)=4$

$x_1-y_1=2$ (Ignore the other solution $-2$ by making the assumption $x_1>y_1$)

$x_1+y_1=14$; $x_1-y_1=2$; $x_1=8, y_1=6$

$\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{6}=2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$

Now to find the square root again to get the fourth root:$\sqrt[4]{X}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}} $

$\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}=\sqrt{\sqrt{2}(2+\sqrt{3})}=\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$

Let $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{y_2}$

$2+\sqrt{3}=x_2+y_2+2\sqrt{x_2y_2}$

$x_2+y_2=2$; $2\sqrt{x_2y_2}=\sqrt{3} \Rightarrow x_2y_2=\dfrac{3}{4}$

$(x_2-y_2)^2=(x_2+y_2)^2-4x_2y_2=4-4\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)=1 \Rightarrow x_2-y_2=1$

$x_2=\dfrac{3}{2}, y_2=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Hence $\sqrt[4]{X}=\sqrt[4]{14+8\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}} =\sqrt[4]{2}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2}}\right)=\sqrt[4]{2}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)=Y$

The solution however is given as $\sqrt[4]{X}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}(\sqrt{3}+1)=Z$, but I feel my calculations are correct.

Why I am getting $\sqrt[4]{X}=Y$ while text book is giving $\sqrt[4]{X}=Z$ ?
So where did I go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you have gone wrong. The two answers look the same to me.

Comment: $$
2^{1/4}(\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=2^{1/4}2^{-1/2}(\sqrt{3}+1)=2^{-1/4}(\sqrt{3}+1)
$$

Comment: I see... they are indeed equal. So in essence my answer is not simplified and not in the correct convention and the textbook answer is? But then what are those conventions and simplification preferences? Because they both look simplified in their own respect. Thanks again!

Comment: [1] Both $Y$ & $Z$ are Same. [2] There is no Universal Convention. Your text book might indicate the "format" in Worked-Out Exercises. [3] It looks like the "format" the text book wants is $(A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4+A_5+\cdots)/A_0$ where we have a Common Denominator , with no more "cancellable" factors. [4] In given Example , we can not check out , but the text book Convention might include a Common Numerator.